# To show the function as concave/convex

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, hessian-matrix

I want to show that $t(a,b)$ where $0\leq a\leq 1,~0\leq b\leq 1$ and $p,q>0$ is as a concave/convex function: 
$$t(a,b)=\frac{\left(\frac{1-b}{2-b}\right) \left(\frac{2 a}{1-a}+b\right)}{p\left(\frac{2 a}{1-a}+b\right)+q\left(\frac{1-b}{2-b}\right)+1}$$

Although the function is twice differentiable, it is really difficult to discuss the Hessian properties since it is ridiculously complected expression.

Is there any alternative way?

Comment: what are p and q?

Comment: Both are positive, I updated the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have $t(0,b)=\frac{b-b^2}{-pb^2+(2p-q-1)b+q+2}$. This expression is neither convex nor concave (draw a plot for p=q=1). Including $a$ as a variable will only make things worse.

Comment: Thanks @Lin, actually my original problem is $(1-a)Log(1+t(a,b))$ which is is too complicated. So I was trying to get some properties of $t(a,b)$. Seems it does not work.

Comment: even with $t(a,b)=b$ your original formula is indefinite

Comment: Is it possible to be $t(a,b)=b$?

Comment: no, just showing that obtaining properties on $t$ alone is not sufficient

Comment: Ok, probably I may work on original problem although it is too complected.