# Concave function and its Eigenvalues

Tags: optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-optimization, hessian-matrix

The following function seems to be concave (I could not prove it)
$$r(a,b)=\frac{1}{2} (1-a) \log \left(p \left(\frac{2 a}{1-a}+b\right)+1\right)$$ where $a\in[0,1)$, $b\in[0,1)$ and $p>0$. 
For $p=0.45$:

[image]

When corresponding eigenvalues of the Hessian matrix are plotted, they are positive and negative:

[image]

However, the function is concave if Hessian is negative semidefinite. So I am confused with this observation.

How can I prove that $r(a,b)$ convex/concave?

Comment: The problem is, in higher dimensions you can't determine the convexity of a function by simply _looking_ at its plot. It's better to put your trust in the hessian matrix

Comment: You can't, because it's not. Trust your analysis: the Hessian is indefinite.

Comment: Aren't you effectively asking the same question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1946006/to-show-the-function-as-concave-convex)?

Comment: That is much more difficult version, I am trying to simplify it as here, but still not easy. However, I am trying to introduce another constraint.